# Having trouble capturing digital TV using DirectShow

Tags: c++, directshow, capture, bda

I have a YUAN MC570QA ATSC/Analog Hybrid Tuner device, I can open the device for capturing analog but I can't find any reference or source code showing how to open the digital tuner. If I enum  devices using CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory I only see DibCom BDA Digital Tuner (Dev1 Path2), however the software that comes with the device lists:

DibCom BDA Analog Tuner (Dev1 Path2)
DibCom BDA Digital Tuner (Dev1 Path0)
DibCom BDA Digital Tuner (Dev1 Path1)

I'd appreciate any pointers in getting DirectShow to capture a channel on the digital tuner.

I would list my c++ code but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to open the digital tuner as a device or if I'm supposed to somehow access the tuner through another interface - not sure which code portion to list here.

Comment: Have you look in GraphEdit or in GraphStudioNext in the Filter-Category "WDM Streaming Capture Devices"? Some capture Devices are only listed there.

Comment: I haven't, will do so. And +1 for mentioning GraphStudioNext, I wasn't aware of that app, very nice.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280126/itunerput-tunerequest-call-ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DVB you have to use [BDA in Directshow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd695354(v=vs.85).aspx). This is not as straightforward as analog capture. For example you have to Submit a tune request before connecting the whole graph. There should be a DTVViewer example somewhere in the sdk. I really think you need to look at the example. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4280973/33499) code I have posted before might also help.

I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kmdF.png) example how a BDA graph should look like ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/a5dd55de-e475-46ed-88b2-876823ba77f2/)).

Comment: Certainly set me on the right track and I have it working now, thanks!

Comment: here's another example graph: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/9a788472-a2e5-41a9-ba6d-d76cccc43140/tv-tuner-what-filters-do-i-need-for-digital-capture-via-directshow?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment

Comment: Thank you for the note here! Appears that if you submit the tune request after building the entire graph, it just does "no" packets at all. Ai ai.  Another thing that helped me (ATSC device) was to lookup and submit both physical channel, virtual channel and subchannel, not sure if needed but it helped :)